# Batch Apex Doubt

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits

Im writing a Batch APEX prgoram.

The program works but it doesnt follow Governor Limits since I have used select statements inside for loop.

The data in the 2 Objects is as follows.

Object 1:

Id   Product                Count

AAC-0023 Sales for Disk         3

AAC-0020 Technical for Disk     2

Object 2 :

SaleId   SalesProduct    SaleCount TechId   TechProduct         TechCount

AAC-0023 Sales for Disk  3   AAC-0020 Technical for Disk    2

How can I compare these two objects?

I can select Object1 & Object 2 in List. But when comparing using traditional Java type for loop and traversing thro 2 lists, 2 records in Object1 corresponds to 1 record in Object2.

Please advice.

Hi Koen ,Sam,

As I have pasted in the above example the data is same.

My doubt is I have to compare two rows from Object 1 to 1 row of Object 2.

In the below example it will extract only 1 row of Object 1 right.

In the above example AAC-0020,AAC-0023 refers to a single record in Object 2 and AAC-0020,AAC-0023 are available in single record.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Using DML statements in for-loops is indeed a very bad idea. Could you add your code to your question, so that we can give you some pointers on how to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the Map type ? This is usually a convienant way to  store one list , and iterate the second verifying if your value is in the map of the first list. you can verify by looking up they key.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but for instance (pseudo code):

```
 Map<id, object 1> mapObjOne = new map<id, obj 1>(scope); //parse your batch scope in a map
 List<object 2> lsObjTwo = [select SaleId,SalesProduct,.. from object 2 where id in:MapObjOne.keyset() ];

for(object 2 objTwo:lsObjTwo){
     objece 1 relatedObjOne = mapObjOne.get(objTwo.SaleId);
      //do something now that you have your object 1 record and it's related object 2 record
}
```

This is a silly example and doesn't take into account a lot of possible things. Mostly which object your batch is running on and the relation type between the two.